# Mac OS Safari users are seeing different CSS Styling

Tags: html, css

I have my friend, who is using Mac OS and Safari, but they are getting this weird, grey square around the accordion icon, and I cannot seem to replicate the issue. I have tried spoofing my user agent to his userage (`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6 Safari/605.1.15`)

I have the HTML/CSS code for the FAQ section and accordion icon:

```
<div class="ac-item">
   <h3 class="ac-head" id="headingOne">
      What is SOLINO?
      <span class="btn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-plus fa-xs""></i>
      </span>
   </h3>
   <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionfaq">
      <div class="ac-body">
         <p>SOLINO is a NFT-driven website offering fun and entertaining minigames with high RTP rates. All profits (100%) from the minigames are shared between the holders of the SOLINO NFTs.</p>
         <p>Link to SOLINO NFTs: coming soon.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.home-faq .accordion .ac-item {
  position: relative;
}
.home-faq .accordion .ac-head {
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 22px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: static;
}
.home-faq .accordion .ac-head .btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  top: 10px;
  background: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}
.home-faq .accordion .ac-head .btn[aria-expanded=true] {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.home-faq .accordion .ac-body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-left: 22px;
  padding-right: 85px;
  color: #D6D6D6;
}
```

[What they should see is this (link to image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTXUN.png)

[This is what they are seeing (link to image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGzrm.png)

Comment: Can you please share an example that reproduces the issue you are seeing? Codepen, JSFiddle etc.

Comment: Please make it a snippet ... Stack Overflow's equivalent of Codepen and JSFiddle. If that's too much trouble, a link to your site would be better than nothing.

Comment: @BrettDonald Yes, here you go. https://lushy.dev/solino/v0.0.1.5/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I’ve reproduced the problem on my Mac.

You have two choices for a fix:

1. Remove the attribute `type="button"` from the `<span>`s which contain your plus signs. I don’t think `type` is a valid attribute for a `<span>` anyway, but it seems to be causing Safari to render it like a default button.
2. Add the CSS declaration `-webkit-appearance: none;` to the rule `.home-faq .accordion .ac-head .btn`. This tells Safari not to render it like a default button.